# how to customize debian installation cd for your needs

Tags: linux, debian

I have with me a Debian CD, which I want to customize for my own needs.
I have extracted the CD and started to change some parts of it, e.g Splash screen (splash.png) installer Title (through isolinux.cfg) etc
These are the things that I want to do:

1. Change the Splash logo at start up of installation to have my own (which is done)
2. Change the grub boot parameters to use my comapny name on it.
3. Change the set of packages in it, so that I can have my own set of packages in it and only those packages are installed
4. Do some post installation steps
5. Customize it's startup and login screen to have my company name.
6. After I am done with this customization, I need to build its live installer CD so that I can install it on my own, on any other system.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu Community Wiki has a page on [Live CD Customization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization); in particular, it sounds like you want [Remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/).

Edit: Another option is [Reconstructor](https://code.lumentica.com/projects/reconstructor/wiki); the downloadable Reconstructor Engine is free, or you can pay to use the online service.

Comment: the link focusses specifically on Linux, i have already taken a look at it. and Remastersys is not helpful either.

Comment: @Frank see edits.